# Indexing a numpy 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose, I have this:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5

ids = [ 1.,          2.,          3.,          4.,          5.,        ]
scores = [ 3.75320381,  4.32400937,  2.43537978,  3.73691774,  2.5163266, ]

ids_col = ids.copy()
scores_col = scores.copy()

students_mat = np.column_stack([ids_col, scores_col])
```

Now, I want to ***`manually`*** show the `ids` and `scores` of those students whose score is more than 4.0.

How can I make the following routine work?

```
print(students_mat([False, True, False, False, False]))
```

**Error**

```
>>> (executing file "arrays.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\arrays.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(students_mat([False, True, False, False, False]))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: You index arrays with brackets, not parentheses: `students_mat[[False, True, False, False, False]]`

Comment: I think you also need to convert that to a numpy array. It seems boolean indexing doesn't work with lists.

Comment: @user2357112, program compiles. But, gives incorrect output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#you need to convert Boolean list to an array to be used when selecting elements.
print(students_mat[np.asarray([False, True, False, False, False])])
[[ 2.          4.32400937]]
```

Comment: @anonymous: 1) because indexing is `[]`, not `()` like it is in matlab, 2) because `arr[[True, False, True]]` is interpreted as `arr[True, False, True]` for backwards-compatibility reasons